# conjoint analysis with ordinal data in R

Tags: r, mlogit

I would like to conjoint analysis with R of an experiment I created with orthogonal design.
The code I found for conjoint analysis had a rating column beside the attributes for each choice.
This is the code I used to implement conjoint.

```
conjoint1 <- read.csv(file="1st_experiment_sheet copy.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
## putting writing down the levels for each attribute. 
first_attirbutes <- c("compelete wp","Normal wp","32GB","128GB","4.7","5.5","With fp","No fp", "4K","FullHD","Sim free","Sim locked")
first_attirbutes.df <- data.frame(first_attirbutes)
conj1.result <- lm(rating ~ water.proof+ memory_size +screen_size +finger_print +Camera +SIM, data = conjoint1)
summary(conj1.result)

##get utilites for each attirbutes
caModel(conjoint1[,7],conjoint1[,1:6])

Conjoint(conjoint1[,7],conjoint1[,1:6],first_attirbutes.df)
```

However, my experiment was to have the applicant reorder a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h based on its attributes not rating them as used on the code above.

I would like to know if there is a possible to apply ordinal based conjoint analysis in R.